# loopback 4 how to use fields filter with custom scope in nested relations

Tags: loopback4

I have four models- purchase, purchase products, vendors, and product.

1. The purchase has many purchase products and vice versa
2. purchase products belong to product and vice versa
3. Vendors has many purchase and vice vera

Now with the following code, I am getting all purchases, purchase-products, and vendors(with field filter) but not able to use field filter with the product.

So can anyone please tell me how to use fields filter with custom scope in nested relations

```
  async find(

  ): Promise<Purchase[]> {
    return this.purchaseRepository.find(
      {

        include: [{
          relation: 'purchaseProducts',
          scope: {
            fields: { name: true, product_id: true }, // not working
            include: [{ relation: 'products' }],
          }

        }, {

          relation: 'vendors',
          scope: {
            fields: { address_line1: false, city: false, state: false, pincode: false, gst_number: false, // working }
          }
        }]
      }
    );

  }
```

purchase.model.ts

```
import { Entity, model, property, hasMany, belongsTo } from '@loopback/repository';
import { PurchaseProduct } from './purchase-product.model';
import { Vendor } from './vendor.model';

@model({ settings: { strict: true } })
export class Purchase extends Entity {


  @property({
    type: 'string',
    id: true,

  })
  purchase_id: string;


  @property({
    type: 'date',
  })
  date?: string;


  @property({
    type: 'number',
    required: true,

  })
  totalprice?: number;
  @hasMany(() => PurchaseProduct, { keyTo: 'purchase_id' })
  purchaseProducts: PurchaseProduct[];

  @belongsTo(() => Vendor, { name: 'vendors' })
  vendor_id: number;
  // Define well-known properties here

  // Indexer property to allow additional data
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  [prop: string]: any;

  constructor(data?: Partial<Purchase>) {
    super(data);
  }
}

export interface PurchaseRelations {
  // describe navigational properties here
}

export type PurchaseWithRelations = Purchase & PurchaseRelations;
```

purchase-products.model.ts

```
import { Entity, model, property, belongsTo } from '@loopback/repository';
import { Purchase } from './purchase.model';
import { Product } from './product.model';

@model({ settings: { strict: true } })
export class PurchaseProduct extends Entity {
  @property({
    type: 'number',
    id: true,
    generated: true,
  })
  id?: number;

  @property({
    type: 'number',
    required: true,
  })
  quantity: number;

  @property({
    type: 'number',
    required: true,
  })
  price: number;

  @belongsTo(() => Purchase, { name: 'purchases' })
  purchase_id: string;

  @belongsTo(() => Product, { name: 'products' })
  product_id: number;
  // Define well-known properties here

  // Indexer property to allow additional data
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  [prop: string]: any;

  constructor(data?: Partial<PurchaseProduct>) {
    super(data);
  }
}

export interface PurchaseProductRelations {
  // describe navigational properties here
}

export type PurchaseProductWithRelations = PurchaseProduct & PurchaseProductRelations;
```

product.model.ts

```
import { Entity, model, property, hasMany, hasOne, belongsTo } from '@loopback/repository';
import { Purchase } from './purchase.model';
import { OrderedProducts } from './ordered-products.model';
import {PurchaseProduct} from './purchase-product.model';

@model({ settings: { strict: true } })
export class Product extends Entity {
  @property({
    type: 'number',
    id: true,
    generated: true,

  })
  product_id?: number;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
    index: {
      unique: true
    }

  })
  name: string;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  image_url: string;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
  })
  description?: string;



  @hasMany(() => OrderedProducts, { keyTo: 'product_id' })
  orderedProducts: OrderedProducts[];

  @hasOne(() => ProductPrice, { keyTo: 'product_id' })
  productPrices: ProductPrice;

  @hasMany(() => PurchaseProduct, {keyTo: 'product_id'})
  purchaseProducts: PurchaseProduct[];
  // Define well-known properties here

  // Indexer property to allow additional data
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  [prop: string]: any;

  constructor(data?: Partial<Product>) {
    super(data);
  }
}

export interface ProductRelations {
  // describe navigational properties here
}

export type ProductWithRelations = Product & ProductRelations;
```

vendor.model.ts

```
import { Entity, model, property, hasMany } from '@loopback/repository';
import { Purchase } from './purchase.model';

@model({ settings: { strict: true } })
export class Vendor extends Entity {
  @property({
    type: 'number',
    id: true,
    generated: true,
  })
  vendor_id?: number;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  name: string;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
    index: {
      unique: true
    }
  })
  mobile_no: string;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    index: {
      unique: true
    }
  })
  email?: string;


  @hasMany(() => Purchase, { keyTo: 'vendor_id' })
  purchases: Purchase[];

  // Define well-known properties here

  // Indexer property to allow additional data
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  [prop: string]: any;

  constructor(data?: Partial<Vendor>) {
    super(data);
  }
}

export interface VendorRelations {
  // describe navigational properties here
}

export type VendorWithRelations = Vendor & VendorRelations;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try including purchase_id on purchaseProducts fields. When you use fields: {key: true} you exclude all the other fields, then the ORM(ODM in case if you use a non-relational database) can't make the join because it needs the foreignKey to do that.

Example (the fields notation that I use is equal to `fields:{key: true}`) :

```
{
   "include":[
      {
         "relation":"userCourses",
         "scope":{
            "offset":0,
            "limit":100,
            "skip":0,
            "order":[
               "id"
            ],
            "fields":[
               "id",
               "user_id",
               "group_id"
            ],
            "include":[
               {
                  "relation":"group",
                  "scope":{
                     "fields":[
                        "id",
                        "otherField" 
                     ]
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Actually there seem to be an issue with fields filter with relations. In above code, for relation vendors, fields name : true was not working, so I had to use field name : false for all other fields

Comment: Ok in that case,  can you upload a minimal code example to replicate that error ?

Comment: Please find the updated code. I have uploaded all models

Comment: Oh, this comment saved my life! Was thinking only key: false is working... once I included foreign key, it all worked!

Comment: Thanks for the info. It is resolved when I add foreign key as true to filter.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final solution working

```
return this.vendorRepository.purchases(id).find({
      include: [{

        relation: 'purchaseProducts',
        scope: {
          fields: { id: false },
          include: [{
            relation: 'products',
            scope: {
              fields: { product_id: true, name: true }
            }
          }],

        },

      },

      ]
    });
```